# Definition of co-occurrence for sequences?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Where can I find a definition for co-occurrence of elements in sequences? I could find only very little material on the internet. I'd appreciate any sources, article, authors and books that deal with the topic.

To give a little background: I'm interested especially in (finite, countable) sequences containing elements that oscillate around a few values and the properties such sequences have. Example:

A = 1, 2, 1, 2
B = 1, 1, 1, 1

If we compare the 1st and the 3rd sequence positions, the values match. If we however compare the 2nd and 4th sequence positions, the values don't match. There are more interesting examples, like: A = 1, 2, 1, 2 and B = 2, 1, 2, 1. Obviously, if we could "shift" one sequence, then we could align both of them.

To know more about such phenomena, I was told that I should have a closer look into co-occurrence.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think that this is a standard concept. If you were told during a private conversation it is probably meant to be something self-evident like "occurring together", i.e., the (repeated, frequent) occurrence of specific finite subsequences such as (1,2).

Comment: Do you say that this is not called "co-occurrence" really and possibly there's no prior literature on this? I'm not so much interested in the oscillation properties, but in the question how the various elements match or don't match together.

Comment: I'm not a librarian, but it's certainly not a standard term in a "normal" 4-year maths curriculum. If your source used the term without any reference to literature then he/she must have assumed that it was self-evident.

Comment: Well, my source was just a colleague who studied maths some years ago. Certainly not an expert on sequences. So, assuming I wanted to have a matrix which displays all matches between all positions of both sequences I could still call it "co-occurrence matrix". I just want to avoid re-inventing the wheel when someone else already coined relevant terms here.

Comment: Sounds reasonable.